# Clojure Mapping a function that returns a list into a flat list

Tags: parsing, clojure, hashmap

This happens when you parse a list of strings and you want to split each one in two, afterwards making a hashmap.

Say we have a list of strings, each one with first line ID and rest data:

```
("#ID
data
More data",
"#another ID
Some more data still")
```

Now suppose that we use the following method that returns a nested structure:

```
(map #(clojure.string/split % #"\n" 2) data)
```

Now if we want to put this into a hashmap, it first has to be `flatten`'d and then `apply hash-map`'d. Is there a way to skip the `flatten` part and by having some `flat-map` return an non-nested structure?

Comment: You're splitting each string into variable number of sub-strings. To split each into no more than two strings use `split` with 3 arguments: `#(clojure.string/split % #"\n" 2)`

Comment: My mistake. The original code was in fact using 3 arguments. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `into`:

```
(into {} (map #(clojure.string/split % #"\n") data))
```